# Use servername in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I've been working with multiple server on my SSMS. Is there any way to connect to particular server (on query) without having connect or "New Query" from Object Explorer Panel. I mean something like this on a query :

```
use dbname
```

Tried this but not working

```
use [servername].[dbo].[dbname]
```

It's a bit annoying, to add a new query just to connect to a particular server.
I also tried clicking Connect on the object explorer , it just connect to the server but not changing the current server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are Linked Servers. You can get to them in SSMS from the following location in the tree of the Object Explorer:

Server Objects-->Linked Servers

or you can use sp_addlinkedserver.

You only have to set up one. Once you have that, you can call a table on the other server like so:

```
  Select * from [ServerName].[DBname].[dbo].[TableName]
```